# Aggregate root optimization with nested objects & big collections

Tags: domain-driven-design

Lets assume scenario:

1. We have `Users` of the system
2. Each `User` have their `Clients` (`Client` is always assigned to one and only one `User`)
3. `Users` upload different `Documents` and a `Document` is always assigned to one and only one `Client`

One of the business rules is that `User` can upload up to X `Documents` in total, regardless of number of `Clients`.

By the book, i would make `User` an aggregate root which would contain collection of `Clients`. Then each `Client` would have collection of `Documents` uploaded for that particular client. When `User` attempts to upload new `Document` for given `Client`, we would load `Users` aggregate root with all of its `Clients` and their `Documents`, and on `User` class i'd have method like:

```
boolean CanUploadDocument()
{
  int numberOfDocuments = //Iterate Clients and sum up total number of their documents;

  //compare to maximum allowed number of docs for User instance
  return numberOfDocuments < this.maxAllowedNumberOfDocuments;
}
```

All well and good, but `maxAllowedNumberOfDocuments` can be thousands or tens of thousands and it feels like a huge overkill to load them all from db just to count & compare them.
Putting `int documentsCount` on `User` seems like breaking the rules and introducing unnecessary redundancy.

Is this the case to introduce separate aggregate root like `UserQuota` where we would load just count of all `Documents` and do the check? Or maybe a value object `UserDocumentCount` which service would get and call method on `User` object:

```
boolean CanUploadDocument(UserDocumentCount count)
{
  //compare to maximum allowed number of docs for User instance
  return count < this.maxAllowedNumberOfDocuments;
}
```

What is the ddd-proper & optimized way to handle this?

Comment: How strong you need the consistency of this rule to be?

Comment: absolute. no user should ever upload single document more than the quota they have. on db side, its a transactional write with optimistic concurrency implemented.

Comment: in this case thus rule must be protected by the Aggregate. You can store a computed `int documentsCount` as an optimisation but inside the `UserAggregate`.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why is that a must? asking because that does introduce unnecessary complexity on DB read side for all of those cases where i just don't need `documentCount` on `UserAggregate` (which are pretty much all cases except `User.UploadDocument()`). Why is the idea with separate `UserQuota` aggregate bad? Could you please elaborate a bit on that? thanks!

Comment: Because in DDD an Aggregate is the *largest* transactional boundary. If you need a bigger one they make the Aggregate bigger (and thus slower).

Comment: Having another Aggregate (UserQuota) it implies that the operation of file uploading is not atomic anymore.

Comment: an alternative is to implement it as a long running process/saga with User and UserQuota aggregates.

Comment: lets put saga/process managers aside for the moment. let me ask just one more detail about aggregate root transactional boundaries. would it be 'in the spirit of DDD' to have 2 aggregate roots for same db entity `User`? Something like `UserAggregate` and `UserWithQuotaAggregate` which would both inherit from abstract `User` where all the common methods would be implemented but `UserWithQuotaAggregate` would have 2 additional methods: `bool CheckUploadQuota()` and `UploadDocument()`? Or does that smell bad?

Comment: I don't see any point in doing so, what would be the common behavior?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, you're completely right. What i actually meant was: 2 aggregate roots where `UserWithQuotaAggregate` inherits from `UserAggregate`? And then `UserWithQuotaAggregate` have those 2 additional methods. No abstract classes.

Comment: I still fail to see what would you accomplish. They would have separate state because they would have separate instances.

Comment: What i would accomplish is to load `documentCount` only when i need it. Its pretty much like having 2 (slightly) different domain models for different type of writes. So, since `UploadDocument` is the only method that needs `documentCount` (which is heavy on DB side), i would extract that behavior into separate subclass and use only when i need that particular method. Now, i am not sure i understand your last point: what does it mean they would have separate state and why is that important? Asking since, one would never operate on both instances at the same time anyways (based on user action).

Comment: Point being, they would never have separate state since: `UserAggregate` cannot affect `documentCount` state in any way. All related to `documentCount` and methods that could change that part of state would be in subclass.

Comment: I now see what you mean. In general, if you need `lazy loading` then you should reconsider your design. Maybe you need two completely Aggregates, no inheritance.

Comment: Well, now we're at the begining. That's exactly why i'm here: i'm trying to re-consider my design to somehow fit this into proper DDD world with that optimization on mind :)

Comment: this is not the beginning, this is the end. You need two Aggregates.

Comment: I must admit i am now completely confused. First you say i need to reconsider my design (which makes me think my idea with 2 aggregates was bad) and now you say i need 2 Aggregates. Could you please put it in one simple sentence if some of the options enumerated above is the one to go with? thanks!

Comment: sorry. You need two Aggregates, with no inheritance between them. The first is User with whatever rules it protects and the second is `UserFiles`. This one manages user's files and protects the quota rule.

Comment: ok, great, that makes complete sense. could you please put it in answer so i can accept it? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a big `User aggregate` is not a solution but not because of the fact that it is slow and it needs an optimization, it's because of the internal fields cohesion.

In order to protect the quota limit the `User aggregate` needs only the uploaded documents and nothing more. This is a sign that you have in fact two aggregates, the second being `UserDocuments` with its method `uploadDocument`. This method internally checks the quote invariant. As an optimization, you could keep a `int countOfDocumentsUploadedSoFar` that is used in the `uploadDocument` method. The two aggregates share only the same identity (the `UserId`).

Note: no inheritance is needed between the two aggregates.

Comment: Great note about criteria for 2 aggregates, unrelated to optimization question. Thanks!

Comment: @deezg You are welcome. You should read this if you haven't already: https://vaughnvernon.co/?p=838

Comment: Thanks for recommendation! Haven't read it so far but definitely will.

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu Thank you for this. Can you explain a little more about what `uploadDocument` would do? would it just add the new document to some sort of `documentsToUpload` field within the class which would then be interpreted by a repository external to the class?

Answer (score 1):

Introducing something like `UserQuota` looks like a good solution. This thing is a real domain concept, it has a right to be an entity. Just now it has one propery `DocumentsCount`, but in time probably you will need `LasDocumentUploadedTime`... `MaxAllowedNumberOfDocuments` can be part of the quota too, it will help when this number changed and the change should be applied only for new quotas, or then quotas became more personal.

Your domain operations should touch quotas too. For example, when uploading a document you initially read appropriate quota and check it, store document, then update the quota.

Comment: thanks for your answer! could you please just clarify a bit your second paragraph? do you think some service should check quota and then run document upload or should `User` aggregate root check quota directly?

Comment: @dee zg Can you live with eventual consistency or the number of documents shall never be exceeded, ever?

Comment: @plalx no, i have to have strong consistency. i am not sure about the other question about number of documents never be exceeded. could you please clarify that one a bit? thanks!

Comment: It's matter of taste I think. I prefer use domain services to perform operations (this approach sometimes called anemic design).

Comment: yes, i used that one alot also but in this particular case i wanted to see purist ddd way.

Comment: I think rich or anemic domain design is an implementation detail. DDD is about design process and methodology, where to place logic is a secondary question. In this particular case you can write domain service with operation `UploadFile`, implementation should read quota, check it, store file, update quota. This implementation provides very strong consistency (on condition that serializable transaction used).

Comment: What about `User` having an internal `UserDocumentUploadPolicy` entity which also tracks the necessary state to enforce the policy? `doc = user.uploadDocument(...); userRepo.save(user); docRepo.save(doc);`. Here `uploadDocument` could do something like `doc = new Document(...); docUploadPolicy.applyForNewDocument(doc); return doc;` where the policy would throw if it is violated. I guess it could also make sense to make the policy a separate aggregate while keeping the factory method on user to create documents.

Comment: @plalx  i like that idea